# Why are my tweet search requests only retrieving 200 tweets every time?

Tags: python, pandas, twitter

I have a script which returns tweets based on a keyword query and then appends this to a CSV. I can't see why in my script, this is only returning 200 tweets every time I run it. It is not the `count` parameter,  because as far as I am aware this returns the number of tweets to return per page, up to a maximum of 100.

Can anyone see what is occurring?

```
def twitter_search(twitter_api, q, max_results = 3000, **kw):
    search_results = twitter_api.search.tweets(q=q, count = 100, **kw, lang = 'en', tweet_mode='extended', )
    
    statuses = search_results['statuses']
    
    #Iterate through batches of results until we get the number we want
    #Enforce a reasonable limit
    
    max_results = min(5000, max_results)
    
    for _ in range(100):
        try:
            next_results = search_results['search_metadata']['next_results']
        except KeyError as e: #no more results when next_results doesn't exist
            break
    
    #create a dictionary from next_results
        kwargs = dict([kv.split('=') for kv in next_results[1:].split("&")])
    
        search_results = twitter_api.search.tweets(**kwargs)
        statuses += search_results['statuses']
    
        if len(statuses) > max_results:
            break
    
    return statuses
```

I think it is to do with the cursor iterating over the next batch of results but I do not know why this is happening...

Comment: I am having difficulty understanding how to integrate the cursor functionality on this page: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/pagination

Comment: Let give it a go. You want to return values from query?

Answer (score 3):

Api's only returning a few requests per user.
That might be the reason you are not getting all of your tweets.

You can read up about this here [Twitter-api](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets) (See the Resource information part)

You can also try and read up on Proxycrawler API to get more tweets than you are getting currently.

Answer (score 2):

Please see the Standard search operators page for a list of available filter operators to learn how to use Twitter Search effectively. See the Working with Timelines page for more information on how to navigate results by since id and max id.

link: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets

Comment: Thank you for your answer, New contributor. If you have the answer, feel free to share it here in addition to providing the reference for the main source of information.

Answer (score 1):

Twitter API had limits per calls for a given period. You can design function in a way that you can wait on limits reach and move from page to page with cursor.

```py
import tweepy

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(API_KEY, API_KEY_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)

twitter_api = tweepy.API(auth)

def twitter_search(twitter_api, q, pages = 50 , **kwargs):

    return [page for page in tweepy.Cursor(twitter_api.search,
                                         q=q,
                                         wait_on_rate_limit=True, 
                                         **kwargs
            ).pages(pages)]
```

This will use cursor to get next pages and wait on rate limit.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter's API is most likely not returning every request. You can utilize the PushShift API here:
 https://pushshift.io/twitter-user-search/